# Using sequelize, trying to make association function like Rails where you call a model as a function and returns the association

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

For example I have a model Project and a model Tasks and a project has many tasks and a task has one project.  I want to write a getter function for the model to retrieve all the tasks assigned to that project.

Here is what I thought I would do and I think is in the right direction but I do not know how to get the id that is going to be assigned to the project.

```
    var Task = sequelize.define('task', {
      title: Sequelize.STRING,
      description: Sequelize.TEXT,
      deadline: Sequelize.DATE
    })

    var Project = sequelize.define('project', {
      title: Sequelize.STRING,
      description: Sequelize.TEXT
    })

    Project.hasMany(Task);
    Task.hasOne(Project);

    sequelize.define('project', {
      findTasks: function(){
        return Task.findAll({where: {"projectId": id}})
      }
    })
```

so on the final sequalize define.. how to I assign that id to the id of the object that is being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize automatically add that function for every association, you don't need to define it.

For a `project` (instance of `Project`) there should be a `getTasks()` function.
Check this paragraph from the documentation: [Associating objects](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#associating-objects)